# How can I execute commands from a CQL file within Neo4j's shell?

Tags: shell, neo4j

I have a file ImportData.cql which populates the database. Is there a way while within Neo4j's shell to execute all the commands within this file by simply calling on the file rather than pasting in each command?

Answer (score 0):

when you .CQL, I am assuming that this file contains bunch of cypher queries.
if yes then you can use "./bin/Neo4jShell -file "name of file" -path "DB-Path"

Thanks,
Sumit